# Is there any reason to assign multiple album covers in iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, appletv, album-art, front-row

I'm ultra-meticulous about my iTunes cover art, but one thing still remains a mystery to me:

iTunes has long supported multiple covers, which can be assigned from anyplace in the interface a single cover can. If I have multiple covers assigned to any particular song in iTunes, is it of any practical use whatsoever?

In other words, will iTunes ever show the other covers (without manually clicking the arrows above the cover panel)? If not, are there any applications that do (including Front Row, iPhone, AppleTV, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the "multiple cover art" feature for various quality differences in scanned albums (I.E. original scan and photoshop retouched version), as well as for second side/inside liners

But as far as I know, only the first cover art item will ever be shown automatically, I have to use the next/prev buttons to access the others.